# "Wer kommt als Nächstes/r dran?"

Tags: declension

Im Satz

> **Was** kommt als Nächste**s**?

kann ich den Gebrauch des Neutrums nachvollziehen – man bezieht sich auf ein Ereignis, das im Folgenden passieren würde / könnte.

Hat *als Nächstes* im angeführten Buchtitel ebenfalls die Bedeutung von "als nächste Aktion / im Folgenden"?

> **Wer** kommt als Nächste**s** dran?

https://www.booklooker.de/B%C3%BCcher/Sigrid-Bernstein+Wer-kommt-als-N%C3%A4chstes-dran/id/A024OX7n01ZZG

Könnte man die neutrale Form durch die maskuline ersetzen, wenn man „als Nächster an der Reihe, der bedient wird“ (z. B. in einer Bäckerei, Metzgerei, etc.) zum Ausdruck bringen möchte?

Wie würde dann auch die Antwort darauf lauten?

"*Ich komme als Nächstes dran*" oder "*Ich komme als Nächste* (die Form richtet sich nach dem biologischen Geschlecht der jeweiligen Person, nicht wahr?) *dran*"?

Vielen Dank!

Answer (score 2):

Grammatikalisch ist an *Wer kommt als Nächster dran?* sicherlich nichts einzuwenden, aber unüblich wäre das allemal. Das Nächste in *Wer kommt als Nächstes dran?* hat eine zeitliche Bedeutung. Damit bezieht es sich nicht auf den grefragten *wen*, sondern auf einen Zeitpunkt. Das *als* ist hier also nicht als Attributsverknüpfung zu sehen.

Der Satz *Wer kommt als Nächstes dran?* bedeutet: *Wer kommt zum nächsten Zeitpunkt dran?* Aber *Wer kommt als Nächster dran?* würde bedeuten *Wer kommt, der Nächste seiend, dran?*

Comment: Die Behauptung, dass *»Wer kommt als Nächster dran?«* unüblich sei, würde ich nicht unterschreiben. Vor 1900 war "als nächster" sogar häufiger in Verwendung als "als nächstes". Seit ca. 1930 ist es umgekehrt, dazwischen wurden beide Formen gleich häufig verwendet. Während "als nächster" seit rund 200 Jahren mit ziemlich gleichbleibender Häufigkeit verwendet wird, nahm die Häufigkeit von "als nächstes" im selben Zeitraum stetig zu. Seit rund 100 Jahren erfolgt das Wachstum sogar exponentiell (Verdoppelung der Häufigkeit alle 20 Jahre) ...

Comment: ... Quelle: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=als+nächster%2Cals+nächstes&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=31&smoothing=3

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Naja, diese Aufstellung hat so ihre Haken. Das Problem hier ist, dass sehr wohl die Phrase *Wer kommt als nächster* in der Literatur in der Vergangenheit üblicher war als *... als nächstes*, aber dennoch sehr unüblich war. Das *Wer kommt als Nächstes* tritt in der Literatur nach diesen Daten eigentlich erst seit den 90ern auf.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast In ihrer Darstellung gibt es zwei Probleme: Ersten ist sie case-sensitive, was in diesem Fall nicht angebracht ist, und zweitens vergleicht sie *als nächster* mit *als nächstes*. Beide Ausdrücke kommen aber vorwiegend in anderen Kontexten als *Wer kommt als Nächste(r)* vor. Das bedeutet, dass diese Daten etwas ganz anderes aussagen, as Sie behaupten, dass sie täten.

Answer (score 2):

Das Pronomen *wer* kann – ebenso wie *jemand* und *niemand* – sowohl als Neutrum wie auch als Maskulinum verwendet werden. Die Verwendung als Maskulinum ist insbesondere in Österreich verbreitet, während in Deutschland und der Schweiz die Verwendung als Neutrum vorherrscht, vgl. [jemand, niemand, wer anderer / anderes (Variantengrammatik des Standarddeutschen)](http://mediawiki.ids-mannheim.de/VarGra/index.php/Jemand,_niemand,_wer_anderer_/_anderes).

Es gibt also jeweils zwei Möglichkeiten. In Deutschland und der Schweiz eher das Neutrum:

1. Jemand anderes kommt dran.
2. Jemand kommt als nächstes dran.
3. Wer kommt als nächstes dran?

In Österreich hingegen eher das Maskulinum:

4. Jemand anderer kommt dran.
5. Jemand kommt als nächster dran.
6. Wer kommt als nächster dran?

### Tendenzielle Adverbialität von «als nächstes»

Der Ausdruck «als nächstes» scheint ein gewisses adverbiales Eigenleben zu haben, indem er auch bei femininem oder maskulinem Bezugswort als Neutrum verwendet wird (vergleichbar mit «demnächst»), und zwar insbesondere dann, wenn er dem Bezugswort vorangeht:

7. Als nächstes kommt mein Bruder dran.
8. Als nächstes kommt meine Schwester dran.

Die Kongruenz zum Bezugswort dünkt mich jedoch leicht besser:

9. Als nächster kommt mein Bruder dran.
10. Als nächste kommt meine Schwester dran.

Wenn der Ausdruck hingegen erst nach dem Bezugwort auftritt, dann ist für mein Sprachempfinden die Sache etwas klarer. Hier würde ich die Kongruenz im Genus bevorzugen:

11. Mein Bruder kommt als nächster dran.
12. Meine Schwester kommt als nächste dran.

Die Verwendung des Neutrums dünkt mich eher umgangssprachlich, wenn auch nicht völlig abwegig:

13. Mein Bruder kommt als nächstes dran.
14. Meine Schwester kommt als nächstes dran.

### Mögliches Femininum?

Auch nicht völlig abwegig dünkt mich nach «wer» ein Femininum, vorausgesetzt, dass aus dem Kontext von Frauen die Rede ist:

15. Wer kommt als nächste dran?

Bei «jemand» + «ander-» hingegen dünkt mich das Femininum unangebracht:

16. *Jemand andere kommt dran.